# How to test my web service?

Tags: java, web-services, jsf, soap

Hey i'm new to JSF and I found the amount of information on basic JSF actions ridiculus.

I'm trying to create a webervice and have auto generated the following :

```
@WebService(serviceName = "Charge")
@Stateless  
public class Charge {

    @WebMethod(operationName = "charge")
    public String hello(@WebParam(name = "name") String name) {
        return "Hello " + name+" !";
    }
}
```

Now so far so good, how do I test it?
if i try to access the web service i get a `resource not available` error.
Should I have added something to `web.xml`?

I'm trying to create a simple SOAP web service and fail to find information on the subject, if you happen to have a good tutorial(not those appearing as first results on Google) I'd love to get a link.

Comment: Do you only want to test the web servise or want to write client ?

Comment: OK. You should able to access your wsld file on the browser. its address should be localhost/Charge?wsdl. it may change depending on your configuration. make sure you have wsdl. then use http://www.soapui.org to test your web service.

Comment: That's the thing i get `resource not available` for that and other variations. and i can't find the wsdl file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I'm not sure why but the fact I had the service as `@Stateless` made it unreachable.

When I removed it I could find the service @ `localhost/<app-name>/Charge?wsdl`